# Leading and trailing spaces in CSV data exported from SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am using a function to pull data from an SQL database and echo it to a file, to be subsequently e-mailed.
However some of the fields in the CSV file (when opened with Microsoft Excel) are showing leading/trailing spaces.

Example of the SQL:

```
function pull_data
{
    sqlplus -s $user/$pass@$db <<EOF
    SET COLSEP ,
    SET LINESIZE 10000
    SET PAGESIZE 50000
    SET NEWPAGE NONE
    SET HEADING OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET ECHO OFF
    SELECT DISTINCT order_number,
                    TO_CHAR(entry_date,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                    TO_CHAR(delivery_date,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                    cust_name,
                    ...
}

echo "$(pull_data $a $b)" > $id.csv
```

Example of the spacing (couldn't upload through Stack Overflow):

http://s3.postimg.org/ekgt9ig4f/Capture.png

What can be done to get the output correct i.e. no leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: what is the query you are issuing? The method you are using to create CSV data is important.

Comment: @Raad `echo "$(pull_data $a $b)" > $id.csv`. We cannot use a `SPOOL` within the SQL.

Comment: ok, but in your `SELECT` statement, are you just using the table columns natively, or are you using a function with them - i.e. `SELECT COL1` vs `SELECT SUBSTR(COL1, 1, 2)`

Comment: @Raad I have updated the question with an example `SELECT`, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks - I have posted a possible solution.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's going to need a bit of hackery - we're going to have to mark that spot and use the marker to put the space back. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: If you have text with words, then you would need to switch to using a regular expression search and replace, as this is more complex. I used tr because the requirement looked simple and it's a simple tool.

Comment: Just a thought : do a "sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF connect $user/$pass@$db" so your username and password do not show in the servers process list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it doesn't actually matter in this case how the columns are selected. The trimming can be done via the OS shell instead of trying to do it in Oracle.

Change the last line from:

```
echo "$(pull_data $a $b)" > $id.csv
```

to

```
echo "$(pull_data $a $b)" | tr -d '\040\011' > $id.csv
```

This uses the linux `tr` (translate) utility to remove spaces (\040) and tabs (\011) from the output.

### Edit:

If the output needs to includes explicit spaces, then replace them with character(s) that are not present in the data, but this is a rather inelegant hack. Change:

```
SELECT COL1,
       COL2 || ' ' || COL3
FROM   ...
```

to

```
SELECT COL1,
       COL2 || '###' || COL3
FROM   ...
```

and the last line becomes:

```
echo "$(pull_data $a $b)" | tr -d '\040\011' | tr --squeeze-repeats [#] ['\040'] > $id.csv
```

Comment: Sorry, that works great, however there is one set of `option1 ||' '|| option2` at the end and the `tr` obviously removes the space there also. What's the best way to sort that (ignore it or something else)?

Comment: Thanks, works great! I was wondering, would it be possible to use `tr` do to `remove spaces before or after a comma` so that it does not remove them between words, basically the end result of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Tim Hall wrote an article on this:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files.php

I find his site one of the best sources on Oracle stuff

If you have CHAR columns use TRIM function to remove leading/trailing spaces